# Block on specific pages and node types

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

I'm trying to make a block display on a specific page and inside a node type; I got this code from drupal.org, but I keep getting this error.

```
Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 178 of /home/content/45/6861545/html/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 354 of /home/content/45/6861545/html/includes/entity.inc).
```

This is the code I used.

```
$match = FALSE;
$types = array('middle_content' => 1);
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
  $type = $node->type;
  if (isset($types[$type])) {
    $match = TRUE;
  }
}

if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 10) == '/test'){
  $match = TRUE;
}

if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0) == "/node/add/middle_content") {
  $match = TRUE;
}

return $match;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually fix that error, see [my answer to a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798047/array-flipcan-only-flip-string-and-integer-values-in-drupaldefaultentitycontr/4803629#4803629).

However, in that case, your code can be simplified *a lot* using menu_get_object():

```
$types = array('middle_content' => 1);
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  if (isset($types[$node->type])) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

And anyway, you should avoid PHP in blocks etc (See [What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-e/2512#2512)), check out [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context). It allows you to configure your blocks (among other things) for conditions exactly like this without having to write code. It is also much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is occurring because `node_load()` either takes an integer or a numeric array of nids, not an associative array. `$node = node_load($nid);` is perfectly valid.

That said, Berdir's answer is a better solution.

Comment: That's what my linked answer is saying exactly. I initially only had that and then edited the other parts in :)

Comment: Well there you go. Upvote for you :)

Comment: Thanks, slightly updated my answer to give some context to that link.