# PHP Snippet: If node is specific node-type and current logged in user is node author

Tags: theming, blocks

I would like to combine these two php codes to display a block only on nodes of a special node-type and when the current logged in user is the author of the node. Any help very much appreciated!

```
$types = array('middle_content' => 1);
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  if (isset($types[$node->type])) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

as found on [Block on specific pages and node types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/block-on-specific-pages-and-node-types/2683#2683)

```
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = arg(1);

  // Load the node if you need to
  $node = node_load($nid);
}

if($node->uid == $user->uid){
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

as found on [How can I check if the author of the current node is the current logged in user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109172/how-can-i-check-if-the-author-of-the-current-node-is-the-current-logged-in-user/109304#109304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7, if you're using PHP Filter, go to the block's settings -> Visibility settings -> Pages -> Show block on specific pages. Select "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)." Use the following code replacing `my_content_type` with the machine name of your content type.

```
<?php 
  $node = menu_get_object();
  global $user;
  if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'my_content_type' && $node->uid == $user->uid) {
    return TRUE;
  }
?>
```

Alternatively, you can select one or more content types under Visibility settings -> Content types. Then you'd only need to check for the node's author, thusly:

```
<?php 
  $node = menu_get_object();
  global $user;
  if (isset($node) && $node->uid == $user->uid) {
    return TRUE;
  }
?>
```

Note the [security issues presented by the PHP filter module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-php-filter-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-et/2512#2512).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I get the following error for both codes: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 4 of .../modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Comment: Hmm...OK, I'll investigate. This code worked on my site.

Comment: Ah, you're probably seeing that on non-node pages (i.e. a Views-generated page)? I've update my response to check if the node object exists.

Comment: Great, now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! When you get a moment, could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!