# drupal and php code

Tags: blocks, input-formats

is it standard or good way to put  code in  block with php fiter format and use another drupal 
benefit (handling users,contents,roles,another modules)?

for example 
i need to use jquery ui dialog. i can use [this module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_dialog). another way is to paste jquery ui dialog script in php code block.

or

i need a special query from database for admin. i have create a page and use content access module and paste my code (including html,jquery.php) in php code block.

or inserting user in drupal database with query in block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in most cases a bad idea, unless there is no other way. See [What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-e), which is pretty much the same question.

Instead of creating a block/page/... with PHP code, I suggest you create a module that exposes a block or uses hook_menu() to expose a page.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it depends. If you want to have the code editable via the UI this is ok. In that case the code may be seen as part of the *content* and I think it fits. Another case would be if you don't want to write/update an own module or theme.

In every other case I would always try to bring the code into the filesystem instead of the database. There are multiple reasons for that:

- reuseability of code (keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
- use of version control (like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/))
- better maintainability of codebase

Apart from that I think many things simply can't be done without writing own modules (and implement [drupal hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6) and stuff like that) and themes but the other way around I don't see such limitations. Correct me if i'm wrong.