# Create a slideshow 

Tags: views

I want to create a slideshow in my site, as in the middle bottom of the page at Blottr.com.

I created the gallery with the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module, but my problem is that I don't know how create a slide form video.
Each of my node has one image, but some nodes have am image with a video. I want to show the  video, when there is a video, and an image when no video is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the slideshow working yourself, it should be pretty simple to get where you want.

All you really need to do is try to display both the video and the image, then in a template_preprocess function for the view, remove either the video or the image field so you only get the one you want.

Alternative you could use js/css to hide unwanted elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global php custom field in view and can manage images/videos using php code.

Comment: plz add details about it

Comment: If we for the moment ignore how extremely short this is on details, -1 on account of me strongly opposing the php module. See [What are the downsides of using 'custom' PHP code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Can you provide a little more detail about how this would work?  As it stands, this answer gives people very little to go on.