# How to use hook_user_login and hook_user_logout to output content to the page

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I came across this post: [execute a php code after a user login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/execute-a-php-code-after-a-user-login) and I implemented the accepted solution. In my implementation, however, I'm trying to output content to the page. This simply doesn't show up. My module name is "alert", and here's the code:

alert.module

```
<?php

function alert_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
    echo 'hi<br>';
  }
}
```

alert.install

```
<?php

function alert_install() {
  // Set the module weight so it can override other modules.
  db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = 99 WHERE name = 'alert'");
}

function alert_uninstall() {
  // Remove the module from the system table
  db_query("DELETE FROM {system} WHERE name = 'alert'");
}
```

alert.info

```
; $Id$
name = Alert
description = Present dialogs or perform redirects based on certain events
core = 7.x
```

I'm implementing this in my theme's `template.php` file. Should this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work in template.php
You need to add this in a module file, check here on [howto](http://drupal.org/developing/modules)
instead of `myTheme` it will be `modulename`
If module name is foo then it will be `foo_user_login`

```
    // @file : foo.module
    function foo_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
      fluenz_user_function($account->uid);
    }
    // and this function name was also different just an FYI
    function fluenz_user_function($uid) {
      for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
        echo 'hi<br>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I've placed it in a module and updated my code above accordingly. Still not working (and yes, I have enabled the module). Nothing seems to happen at all.

Comment: `hook_user_login` IS getting called because I was able to successfully log a watchdog message in my `alert_user_login()` method. But I don't see the `hi<br>`'s on the page.

Comment: As destination page is different you wont be able to see all the echo s, but if you put a `die(__FUNCTION__)` after for loop you will probably see that it halted right after all echo statements.

Comment: Use drupal_set_message() instead of echo.  It will preserve messages across page redirects.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7

Answer (score 1):

[hook_user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7), and [hook_user_logout()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7) are not thought to be used to alter the content of a page. They are thought to record the fact a user logged in, or logged out, and eventually set a message with [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7). To notice that the answer for the question you are referring is talking of executing code, not printing a string through `print()`, or `echo()`.

`hook_user_login()` could be used to set a global variable, or a static variable (see [drupal_static()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7)) that is retrieved from another hook.

For altering the content of a page, there are other hooks; which one you should use depends from what exactly you want to achieve.