# Why am I getting a "page not found" error for this implementation of hook_menu()?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

Here's the implementation of `hook_menu()` in my theme, "myTheme":

```
function myTheme_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['ajax'] = array(
        'title' => 'AJAX',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    $items['blog'] = array(
        'title' => 'sonia blog',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}
```

example.com/ajax is working fine, but example.com/blog is returning me a "page not found" error. I have cleared my cache.

Do you have any idea about what is going wrong?

**EDIT**
One of the commenters suggested that I need a `page_callback` property. However, the documentation on `hook_menu` does not say that it's required. Regardless, I tried adding this callback but still no luck. Here's the code with it:

```
function myTheme_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['blog'] = array(
        'title' => 'sonia blog',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page callback' => 'myTheme_callback_blog',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}

function myTheme_callback_blog(){
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `/blog` is not already defined by another module ? Did you try another path, just for checking ?

Comment: `/blog` is used by the core Blog module

Comment: Are you defining this in a *theme* or a *module*?

Comment: Both your menu items are missing the `page callback` property, see [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more details

Comment: My ! How could I miss that ?

Comment: @Clive -- I didn't think this was a required property. Certainly the documentation for hook_menu() doesn't specify it as such. And the fact that the `ajax` menu entry works fine also suggests that this isn't the issue. Regardless, I added a page_callback and it still doesn't work (see edit to my post).

Comment: @MPD - in a theme.

Comment: @Laxman13 -- I don't have that module enabled.

Comment: @maxedison It's only not required if the item can inherit the page callback from a parent item. So if the path 'page' has a `page callback` then the path `page/sub-page` will inherit it. Otherwise its required or Drupal has no function to run to get the page content :) Not sure why the `ajax` path works though so maybe that's not quite right. As others have said though, `blog` is already a defined path so you need to alter it in `hook_menu_alter()` rather than redefine it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you cannot define a `hook_menu()` implementation in a theme; it should be defined in a module.

When you make changes to a `hook_menu()` implementation, you need to ensure that you rebuild the menu router, as well. To that end you can manually look at your database's "menu_router" table to see if the callback is being registered.

Comment: This is correct; a theme can implement `hook_menu_alter()` on Drupal 7, but it cannot implement `hook_menu()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement these in a theme, which will not work; you need to add these in a module.

See [How to use hook_user_login and hook_user_logout to output content to the page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24197/how-to-use-hook-user-login-and-hook-user-logout-to-output-content-to-the-page/24200#24200).