# CKEditor doesn't show JavaScript

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have Drupal 7 with CKEditor 3.6.2.7275 under Wysiwyg module. In configs of Wysiwyg I unchecked all the checkboxes for "Cleanup and output" category. Plus unchecked "Limit allowed HTML tags" for Full HTML text format.

When I try to edit the page, containing javascript inside, the <script type="text/javascript"> is inside the <textarea> for content editing. But it's not shown by CKEditor when I click source button. So it's undoubtedly CKEditor filtering.

What should I do to make CKEditor show javascript?

Comment: one solution is add another textarea field without wysiwyg to your content type for your javascript code

Answer (score 4):

Drupal, like most Content Management Systems, has security systems in place to filter most javascript during submission so site members can’t do ugly things via scripting. In most cases, that’s a good thing. When you’re scratching your head trying to figure out a way around it, not so much.

You can hard-code a script into the template, if you need it on all the pages and it works. But just adding a a single, inline javascript into a Drupal node is not as easy as it seems.

***There may well be a prettier way to do this***, but here is a quick way out in case you need it:

First,  put the script on your server, someplace it’s easy to find. I usually have a  “scripts” folder in my sites/all folder.

Second, when do your post, set your input filter to PHP

Third, do a php include where you’d like to place the script. Something like this:

```
<?php include('sites/all/scripts/my_javascript.js'); ?>
```

And there you go. Inline javascript. I guess in the most common scenarios Drupal is used for, having `<script>` available without filtering would be very foolish security wise. Unfiltered js in a webform makes for a very insecure setup.

Comment: That will get the job done but make sure you understand the security implications of using the custom PHP filter before enabling it. It's actually been removed entirely from drupal 8 core. Have a look at this post. [what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args)

Comment: @munkiepus  Although I did not say outright it was very hackish, I did put bold text to say it's not pretty.

There are so many ways to add js on a page with drupal either in theme or module layer, you don't really need  php in a form to add js. Ever.

Comment: I appreciate that, I was just trying to add a bit of useful info that I thought was relevant and helpful, don't want to step on any toes ;)

Comment: Lol, no way friend your comment is totally acceptable: my answer is indeed a bad hack. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';
```

in the Advanced Content Filter of CKEditor configuration. Be careful of security considerations.

Answer (score 1):

On /admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full open fieldset "Advanced content filter" and in textarea "Extra allowed content" add *script*

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before,but it's becuase of **CKeditor Content Filtering feature**

> Configure input data filtering in CKEditor. See this [blog post](https://ckeditor.com/blog/Upgrading-to-CKEditor-4.1/) for more information about ACF.

You can Handle it by two solutions, the first one is preventing CKEditor  filter contents, 
it's an easy solution just Disabled "Advanced Filtering Feature" at `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full`  but I don't recommend it in all cases.

Better solution is specified your tags at `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full`(if you use Full filter, you can change it based your format in used) > **Extra allowed content** > **Extra allowed content**  enter you desire tags, in your case just enter **script** in the textarea. save the form and clear the cache.

[image: Exclude script tags from filtering in CKeditor]