# 7 - How can I add a region inside another region?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm surprised I can't find the answer to this online.

I'm currently creating a custom header for my drupal site, so I've created a custom_header region in the .info and a region--custom-header.tpl.php file. Inside the region, I need to add another region.

I've tried to print the other region inside the header region, but nothing is showing up.

Good practise or not aside, how can I do this?

Comment: Can't you change the position of region in `page.tpl.php`?

Comment: @SumitMadan Yes I could, and that works. but I have quite a number of page templates so I want to group all regions that belongs to the header inside the header region.

Comment: If you created any region that will need to be changes in every tpl file. May be this post can help you http://groups.drupal.org/node/195038.

Comment: No You cant do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it that way. But its drupal and it spread true love, so worry not, heres a solution.

1. Activate php filter under modules
2. Create a custom block
3. add `<?php print views_embed_view(yourviewname, block); ?>`

Comment: **Note:** This answer is perfectly valid, but there are risks with enabling PHP Filter, you can **[read about them here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args#answer-2512).**

Answer (score 0):

No You cant do that. Whatever use case you're looking for can be achieved through blocks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it'll get hacky and fragile. This sounds like a 'golden hammer' problem, a different tool would likely work better.

Have you considered using Panels or Display Suite to accomplish what you're doing? Panels are better if you want a more WYSIWYG type interface, Display Suite is better if you're comfortable coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with template files or lack coding skills, you can use

### [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

> **An Overview of Panels** The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its
> core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually
> design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with
> other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages
> that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the
> node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very
> fine grained permissions.

With Panels, you can add more regions to your nodes.

With mini panels, you can add blocks with regions inside them.