# How to make a Data Selector a negative value in a rule action?

Tags: rules, actions

I create a rule and inside it I added a action, this action involves a data selector: **node:field-labpoints**. I need to make this data selector a negative value.

I tried with `-node:field-labpoints` and `-[node:field-labpoints]` but it is not accepted.

look my capture:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to do this.

Either you use **PhP filter**, which will add under "data selector" and "add offset" a new option, "php evaluation", which will allow you to post-treat this value. Then you'll just have to set `return intval(- $value);`

Or you can use **whole Rules**, by :

1. Action: **Add a value**, and select your [node:field-labpoints]
2. Action: **Calculate a value**, and make it negative
3. In your action, **use this value** instead of the one you selected with the selected.

Comment: I don't have the `Add a value` action. Do you have any other rules module to have this action?

Comment: for those of you looking for a link to PHP Filter (like me):  PHP Filter is a module included in core!  It's already there (like magic).

Comment: PHP Filter it's bad practice. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2512/6309