# Make block appear on some pages but not others

Tags: blocks, users

How can I tell a block to appear on user profiles, like `/user/1`, but not on other pages where the beginning of the path is the same? So for instance, if I have a view set up at `/user/1/articles`, or `user/1/messages`, how can I tell the block to appear in the main user profile but not on the articles or messages pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only option is to use a PHP snippet to set the visibility.

Under `Visibility settings` select `Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)` copy and paste the snippet below.

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'user' && !arg(2)) return TRUE;
?>
```

For this to work you would also need to enable the `PHP filter` module.

Note that it's not generally recommended to use the PHP filter, but in some cases it might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Yeah that ended up working. Why exactly is it not recommended to use the php filter?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args), and [this page](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php) on drupal.org for the general reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it visible only on

```
user
```

and only for `authenticated user` role.