# How do I display tokens in a block using PHP code?

Tags: 7, blocks, tokens

What is the way to use tokens in PHP code?
I need to show the user profile picture URL, but the following code doesn't work.

```
<?php
  echo "[current-user:picture:url]";
?>
```

How do I display tokens in a block? I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/token_filter use this module

Comment: a detail blog: http://goo.gl/77zEds

Answer (score 2):

I dont recommend using PHP in a block for  [many reasons](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args).

I would recommend you to use proper implementation of [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) and [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) to do you custom PHP codes in there.

Comment: Don't be offput by saadlu's suggestion - it is remarkably easy to make a module to return a block, and   would be much easier in the long run (http://goo.gl/LdWeAM).

Checkout the examples project if you want to see how it works (https://drupal.org/project/examples)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason to use tokens for this purpose, you could just get the profile picture url directly from the user object:

```
global $user;  // get the current user
$user = user_load($user->uid); // load all fields etc for user object
$picture_url = $user->picture->uri;
echo $picture_url;
```

I totally agree with saadlulu above though - much better to put this code into a module.

Not sure if it suits your purposes, but a quick search of d.o also brings up an existing contributed module that will display the user picture for you:

https://drupal.org/project/user_picture_block

Answer (score 0):

You could try [token_replace](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7)

```
token_replace($text, array $data = array(), array $options = array())
```

> **Parameters**
>
> **$text:** A string potentially containing replaceable tokens.
>
> **$data:** (optional) An array of keyed objects. For simple replacement
>   scenarios 'node', 'user', and others are common keys, with an
>   accompanying node or user object being the value. Some token types,
>   like 'site', do not require any explicit information from $data and
>   can be replaced even if it is empty.
>
> **$options:** (optional) A keyed array of settings and flags to control
>   the token replacement process. Supported options are: