# Is it a great idea to upload php instead of writing phps in drupal interface

Tags: security

At each time I write PHP code in blocks and views, I always think about this question : ["What are the downsides of using 'custom' PHP code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args/2512#2512).

Is it a great idea to make users able to send php files instead of writting it. It would be a first step to manage the code after with name conventions to find the code easily and to be also able to read easily the code?

Or it's just a stupid idea that will generate a security mess ??

Comment: What feature would this support? This seems so wrong to me that I almost get upset! Cant say if I find eval or uploaded code worse than the other, but both are really really wrong. Dont do it. At all. Ever.

Comment: Just to clarify that this doesn't have anything with jramby or this question in particular to do. I get a bit upset every time I see this type of question, and habitually down-vote any answers that suggest using the PHP-filter.

Comment: I understand, but is there any solution that doesn't suggest using PHP-filter ?... Because in any case this is a real need in most of drupal install... tell me if I'm wrong... and don't be upset too much ;)

Comment: Just write your own modules instead of inserting php code everywhere. It will be safer, more robust and reusable.

Comment: Well, jramby, that's why I asked what feature this functionality would support. Why do you need this? I even run my servers with `eval()` disabled in PHP. I can think of no reason to use it, but there could be reasons I'm not thinking off. My suggestions is that you rather ask "How do I implement feature X without php-filter".

Comment: Part of me is actually surprised/irritated that `php.module` is still in D8 core. I could swear there was talk of removing it.

Comment: @Letharion, This is [the question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/how-to-generate-a-drupal-generated-like-using-l-in-a-block-without-php-filter) you asked for... but the purpose is something beyond this feature

Comment: Chapabu, there was talk about it, but the issue sort of stalled. I agree, I find it quite irritating. (But I didn't really participate either, so I'm not really allowed to complain)

Comment: @Letharion Same...I want to throw my toys out of the pram but I didn't contribute to the discussions :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to put PHP codes in hooks... And anyone could say that it's insane to create a module just for one or two lines of codes... But most of time, drupal users has to do somthing like this several times in drupal. So why not combine all these hooks in one module that we might call whatever we want. So then just well-comment the code for good reading.

The little snag is : is there hook for each actions where we can add php code ?