# Possible to set user privileges on part of the text?

Tags: nodes, users

In my node I have embeded a view using php snippet in body field. When regular user edits it I don't want him to accidently delete the snippet, is there a way to hide or lock that part of the text from that user so no matter what he does the snippet will remain there? Should I add a custom field just for it or are there a better options?
Also note, that the snipped could be placed in the middle of the body field content.

Thanks!

Comment: in your body field right?

Comment: yes, in the body field

Comment: check this out https://www.drupal.org/project/defaulttextfornode but it don't have privileges

Comment: seems good, but the problem is I want to be able to to choose the placement of that snippet(above or below the body field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no ways to do this. And there shouldn't be. First of all, read [PHP in database: bad practice but](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/70297/16495) - this addresses exactly the situation you have here. Long story short: don't do it. Turn off PHP module if you don't need it.

And why you don't need it? Because there is [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module.

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.

Exactly what you want to do, but without any snippets in user editable texts.

Comment: @EverWondeR It might be a bit hard to set up, I admit, but it's worth it. Ping me in chat if you need additional help with it. Or ask a question, if it's something big enough to be worth it.

Comment: @EverWondeR Glad it was easy for you. For me - I *always* need a manual and half an hour to get it straight ;)

Comment: I know the feels, that was the same for me when I was dealing with taxonomy views firsthand.