# Showing block in specific urls and content types

Tags: blocks

I'm using this code to show block in specific urls and content types.

```
<?php
  $match = TRUE;
  // block is visible on the content types entered here
  $types = array('product_display' => 1, 'page' => 1);
  $url = request_uri();
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $match = isset($types[$node->type]);
  }

  if (strpos($url, "somewhere")) {
    $match = TRUE;
  }
  // copy paste these for additional URLs
  $tids=array_keys(taxonomy_get_children(7));
  foreach($tids as $tid) {
    if (strpos($url, "taxonomy/term/".$tid)) {
      $match = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }
  return $match;
?>
```

It works but the block shows in some other urls too, any idea why?

Comment: can you give some example URL's where it shows, and where it doesn't?

Comment: How are you not able to use the Block configurations page? From Structure > Blocks > Configure (for each block) you can specify specific pages and which content types you can show this block...

Comment: @Geoff it shows on product display which is true and it shows on about us page which is not true

Comment: Infact, you defined the $match variable to TRUE. Even if the "IF" condition fails, it returns $match as TRUE; I suggest you to define the $match = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

You could do one more thing over it.

Just remove the block from the assigned region and render that block using `module_invoke()` in the template file `page.tpl.php`.

```
<?php
  $match = TRUE;
  // block is visible on the content types entered here
  $types = array('product_display' => 1, 'page' => 1);
  $url = request_uri();
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $match = isset($types[$node->type]);
  }

  if (strpos($url, "somewhere")) {
    $match = TRUE;
  $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  print $block['content'];
  }
```

Render your block with the applied condition as you want.
If you just want to display block at some specific urls and content types.

It works well for that!

Comment: i'm working with omega and omega does'nt have a page.tpl.php.what's your idea ?

Comment: how to tell drupal which region block should show ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use the PHP filter in the block settings. Once thing can be done instead. In your custom module you can create a [hook_page_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to remove the block. Yes of course you have to edit the module file if you want to show the block in other sections even in Production but enabling PHP Filter can create issues. Check [here](http://www.valuebound.com/blog/enabling-php-filter-in-drupal-7-core-what-can-go-wrong) and [here too](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args).
Anyway, if you want to use the hook then the code will be,

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $region_name = 'sidebar_first'; // The region where the block is placed.
  $block_name = 'system_navigation'; // The name of the block.
  $types = array('product_display' => 1, 'page' => 1);

  // Only the content type condition shown.
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    if (!in_array($node->type, $types)) {
      if (isset($page[$region_name][$block_name])) {
        $page[$region_name][$block_name]['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've only shown the condition with content type, I am sure that you can add the later 2 conditions with URL & taxonomy terms.

Comment: Thx but i don't want to create a module for that because it's not just one block that i want to show

Comment: Well, by this code you can show/hide multiple blocks based on your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to obtain a snippet that shows a block in a page if the path contains a given string OR if the page is a node of a given content type. I'm sure it could be improved, but for the moment it serves his purpose and doesn't generate any error.

```
<?php
  // Check proper node type.
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if (isset($node) && ($node->type == 'family' || $node->type == 'species')) {
      return TRUE;
  }

  // Pages to match on (mynotes or mynotes* - using newline character).
  $pages = "mynotes\nmynotes*";
  // Get current alias.
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  // Compare with the internal and path alias (if any).
  $page_match = drupal_match_path($path, $pages);

  if ($path != $_GET['q'] || $page_match) {

    // Check if match with internal or alias.
    if ($page_match || drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $pages)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  else {
    return FALSE;
 }
?>
```