# Getting the nid for a teaser

Tags: nodes

I know how to get the nid for a node, but not for a teaser. I want to show a button in the teaser, created by a field with the PHP filter, that allows printing the node to pdf, but that requires the nid. The functions that work in the node, like menu_get_object(), don't work in the teaser.

Googling this has only brought up methods of printing a teaser if you already know the nid, not getting the nid if you only have the teaser. It should be available; it appears in the id for the teaser.

EDITED: I went with the suggestion posted below by f0ns. I don't understand why the nid is not available when it's in the teaser's id in the html, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, if you're not not on the node page, there's really no context from which to retrieve a teaser's node. This may need to be done at the template level, or in a preprocess function for the teaser view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use hook_node_view and for $view_mode == teaser you can add your logic.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7

Comment: Thanks, looks like this would work in a module. My use case is a field on the teaser with the PHP filter. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I don't recommend using the php filter, why not to use it: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args

Comment: I agree with you, but I took over a site not developed with Drupal best practices (hacked core - dead kittens), and there's a lot of this in the site already.

Comment: Still the method I suggested would be the fastest most secure way that I know of to implement the functionality that you want.

Comment: Thanks, f0ns, your post led me in the right direction. This comment on the page you  linked: https://api.drupal.org/comment/48278#comment-48278 gave me what I needed to get it done. I've marked yours the answer. (Note: for anyone who copies/pastes, there should be quotes around teaser as in $view_mode == 'teaser')