# Rewrite field for a specific row?

Tags: 7, views

I see that in views the Rewrite the output of this field option affects all rows. Is there a way, using php or something, to rewrite the output of row #4 only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your theme's template.php file:

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){
  dpm($vars);
  if ($vars['view']->name == "VIEWNAME" && $vars['view']->current_display == "DISPLAY" && $vars['id'] == 4){
    $vars['fields']['title']->content = 'blahblah';
  }
}
```

Clear the cache.

Replace VIEWNAME, DISPLAY and 4 with your appropriate values.

Then inspect the $vars['fields'] with dpm output and rewrite the output how you want for the field in question. You may use 'raw' value, but remember to [sanitize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/sanitization/7).

Comment: I'm not familiar with dpm, do I need to install the devel module?

Comment: Yes you need to install devel.

Comment: "dpm($vars];" causes my page to go blank and I have devel enabled.

Comment: Small typo: needs to be dpm($vars);

Comment: great, one last question. What if I want to use another variable from the view instead of out putting the text blah blah blah for the 4th title field. Ex: I want to print the user name.

Comment: All the fields are on available in $vars['fields']. If it is not, then add it to the view, or use global $user for user, or load it. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

just thought of a solution using the [views php module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php).

I added a view result counter field and then a php field which I put:

```
<?php
    if ($row->counter == 4) {
      print 'HELLO THERE!';
    }
    else {
       print $row->title;
    }
?>
```

## **After reading the accepted answer to this question [What are the downsides of using 'custom' PHP code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args)** which was mentioned by f0ns (see comment below)

The biggest reason being:

> If your CMS allows execution of PHP then an attacker who finds a
> security vulnerability of XSS or privilege escalation can now use your
> server for enormously malicious things (as part of a DDOS, sending
> spam, hosting malware, hacking into other sites/databases on the
> server, hacking into other servers on the network that might be behind
> firewalls). In addition to making small vulnerabilities more painful,
> this makes the site a more likely target of attack if its known that
> it can be used to execute php.

**Thus, I decided to go with the answer I accepted, which does not use Views PHP**

Comment: Views PHP module puts your code in DB which is kinda bad (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args), might be better to put your code in a hook_view_pre_render function in a custom module.

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 0):

Use the view template file and use `$id` variable. If you are using `$id` variable then you will get id 4 for row 4.