# How to display an image from theme directory to a drupal block by php code?

Tags: theming

I want to load an image from my theme directory inside a block. I am using the following code:

```
<img src="<?php print $base_path .$directory; ?>/images/oil-ad.png" alt=''oil ad">.
```

But it is not working. However I have enabled PHP Filter and php text format.

Comment: images is in drupal root folder? have you checked it's access permission?

Comment: Yes, image is inside theme>image folder and the access is given to administrator for php filter. I updated the code above that you see.

Comment: check this code to get theme path instead :  drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME');

Comment: I mean instead of $base_path.$directory

Comment: Should i use like this? <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>/images/oil-ad.png" alt=''oil ad">.

Comment: Be sure you know the implications of using PHP Filter. Best practices of Drupal are to NOT use that the PHP Filter module. Here is an excellent run-down of things you should know using PHP Filter: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args

Comment: try this :
<img src='"'.<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>.'/images/oil-ad.png" alt=''oil ad">'

Comment: And the THEME_NAME should be replaced with the name of theme folder which image exists inside .

Comment: And I'm agree with Brady . this is not the best practice

Comment: Thank you. for both answers. I need to do it now as i am beginner.

Comment: I think you've been using Joomla before starting Drupal,am I right?

Comment: Joomla and wordpress.

Comment: If you are a beginner with Drupal, please do not use the PHP Filter. You should be an intermediate to advanced level with Drupal before turning PHP Filter on. There are a lot of serious implications using this module, see my link. If you need to put an image in a block, use HTML.

Comment: Usually I create custom blocks through views. But in a specific theme it is not possible with views and html.

Comment: Then the answer is to create a custom module to create your blocks. Or use a contrib module such as Block Theme https://www.drupal.org/project/blocktheme where you can create templates for blocks.  I wish they would remove PHP Filter from core. It creates very, very bad habits among themers.

Comment: I have run and built Joomla and Wordpress sites before as well. Drupal is a completely different ballgame. Drupal is more like an enterprise CMS than the aforementioned other two. I would humbly suggest reading how to do things the "Drupal way" and not what you remember from Wordpress or Joomla - it will reward you in the end.

Comment: I want to study a lot about drupal. The tutorials in the net is for beginners and advanced tutorials and books are paid version. I don't have access to pay from here.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you show the rest of the code? Notice also that the code you are showing contains `alt=''oil ad"`.

Comment: That is all of the code i used in a block. And thanks from all of you who commented and told me some new technics. Now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image "alt" attribute, you have 2 single quotes before ***oil ad*** and a single quotation mark following it. That syntax doesn't look right to me. Maybe THAT is causing some error somehow? If not then read on below for further narrowing down your issue.

Assume you used [admin/structure/block/add](http://admin/structure/block/add) to create that block, with a "body" in which you added that `img` tag.

When doing so, you also need to select the "*text format*" (below the body) to be used. You wrote you used "php text format", though I'm assuming you mean "test format"="PHP code".

To further ivestigate where your problem is actually coming from, try to further narrow down your issue. By FIRST creating such image tag without using any PHP code. And instead use some text format like 'Full HTML' and/or 'Filtered HTML', something like so (I intentionally did not correct the syntax of the alt attribute, because that might produce the error you're searching for ...):

```
<img src="/some/path/that/is/hardcoded/images/oil-ad.png" alt=''oil ad">.
```

If that works then have a confirmation that your issue is NOT because of some text format configuration issue related to using the "img" tag.

Comment: Thank you. I did this way and solved the problem.
<img src='"'.<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>.'/images/oil-ad.png" alt=''oil ad">

Comment: No. I replaced the $base_path.$directory with drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME');
it solved my problem.