# How to compare 2 row fields in a view and don't display them if some conditions are verified?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a view table with 12 Fields & 10 Rows and I wish to compare two known fields with defined field names and check if both fields are:

1. If data partially matches (Field 1 with Field 2 or vice versa) then display rows, e.g.:

   - Field 1: Apples, Oranges.
   - Field 2: Oranges, Grapes.
2. If none matches then don't display either of the two rows.
3. If row data is blank for one of the fields then don't display them.

Comment: do you have some advance? If some of the answers help you you can check it as accepted, if you don't know hot you can read this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: finally, do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

### [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> - Equal To
> - Not Equal To
> - Greater Than
> - Less Than
> - Empty
> - Not Empty
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i got views condition working for a Blank field => text out but I cannot get to work with "Contain" if it has a partial text match in either of the fields.

Comment: looks like you will need custom work. You can override the view's template, here is a [tutorial](http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/views/how-to-create-custom-template-view-drupal-tutorial-article#.VqSK7YUrKUk). All you gotta do is use php and an IF statement. For partial match, you're gonna have to figure out the php for that. You can ask that over at [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. To filter your rows in your view, in the filter criteria add a `Global: PHP` field, in the *Filter code* edit you can have access to all the rows of the view (`$handler->view->result`) and to the values of the current row (`$row`) then you check your condition and if the code returns `TRUE` the current row is removed from the results.

Comment: **Note:** This answer is perfectly valid, but there are risks in using Views PHP, [you can read about them here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args#answer-2512), use at your own risk. Even on the Views PHP module page there is this [picture](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/IMG_20140930_162850.jpg)

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks for the note, is important that the OP have this information.