# How to use a math field to calculate a product of an existing file?

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to have a field (`field_result`) that would display a number that results of the product of an existing field (`field_1`) on the same content type (let's call it `book`) and a fixed number (let's say 3.5).

As per [another user suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189373/5645), I decided to give up using [Computed field](http://dgo.to/computed_field) module and use the [Math Field](https://drupal.org/project/mathfield) module instead. After reading [its documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2484065) I configured field_result as follows:`[field_1:0:value] * 3`

Unfortunately I didn't succeed on making it work, despite I made sure `field_1` exists and has a value: I do not get any result (Blank field). I also tried with `2 + 2` with no results

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I test with the same values and it works

Comment: Is your field_1 an integer or decimal field? if it's a text field that might be what's causing the problem.

Comment: clear the cache?

Comment: Started from scratch and it worked now with the same configuration. Thanks for your replies.