# How do I get an entity reference parent using tokens?

Tags: 7, entities, tokens

## Setup

I have an entity reference chain that is kind of complicated. It's basically using Drupal to build a dynamic database with nodes being the tables and entity reference acting to store external keys.

An example might be:

1. Video Games - name, genre, description, release (entity reference)
2. Release - name, release type, region, release date

I am using [Node Title Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module to populate the title of the release with `[Release Type] [Region]` if the title is left empty. For example a release may look like: "Normal US"

## The Problem

I would like to change that title to use the parent node name like `[Parent Entity:name] [Region]` So the release title would look like: "Pokemon Red US"

## The Question

How do I find the parent node given an entity reference field? I know there could be multiple parents but I'm ok with just taking the first one or whatever. It's mostly just present to help autocomplete fields and views presentations.

I considered [Computed Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module but it stores PHP in the database which is [always a bad idea](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args).
I also installed the Entity Reference Tokens module but it doesn't seem to have parent relationships.
I'm confident this is possible as I have already done something similar in views.

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal 7. Updated the tags to reflect.