# How do I create a new variable?

Tags: 7, views

I want to use a new variable in a view using global PHP. Between the available variables, I have `$row->my_field`, and I want to put its value in a new variable.

```
$new = $row->my_field;
echo $new
```

I'm using this code in *Output Code*. I get the following error:

> Syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) ...

I cannot even use `array_unique()`.

Is it possible to add a new variable? and Is it possible to use a function like `array_unique()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a new variable?

YES

[image]

> Is it possible to use a function like `array_unique()`?

Yes, as long as you have an array to pass as a parameter.

**PS:** You shouldn't be using Views PHP to begin with; you should create a template file for your view and add the PHP code there.

[What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-php-filter-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-et)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have a problem about array_unique function, May you see it? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214829