# How to enable PHP in a field?

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a content type in Drupal 8 and I added a field named "body". But I'm unable to use PHP code in this field.

How can I enable PHP in my "body" field?

Comment: Please don't ?!?

Comment: I would encourage you to find an alternate method, this is a very bad idea. If you expand your question as to what exactly you need to do, most likely there is a way to accomplish what you need to do without having to use PHP that way.

Answer (score 9):

Using PHP in your body field is considered bad practice. Read: **[What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-php-filter-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-et/2512)**

Even in the module page it clearly says:

> **Warning**
>
> Enabling this module can cause security and performance issues as it
>   allows users to execute PHP code on your site. There are better
>   alternatives out there that do not expose such vulnerabilities on your
>   site.

The proper way to add your PHP:

- Use a preprocess function in **theme_name.theme** located in your theme's folder.
- Create a custom module that uses [hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/8.2.x) or preprocess functions.

Furthermore, [Twig has several filters and functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation#reference) that you can make use of. Which in some cases, you don't even need to use PHP at all.

Answer (score 4):

Install and configure [PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) module.

> The PHP Filter module adds a PHP filter to your site, for use with
> text formats.

Note: The PHP filter core module has been removed from core starting with version 8.x. See also [PHP filter overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/php/overview).