# Computed field : Count number of elements in multiple entity reference list

Tags: 7, entities

I have multiple entity reference field in the user form. I just want to do the sum of each element checked by the user in its profile.

I made this code but it doesn't work (I don't really know php actually) :

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $Balance;

$modeling_softwares = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_3d_modeling_softwares')); 
$database_sofwares = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_database_management_softwa')); 
$sig_softwares = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_geographic_information_sof')); 
$operating_system = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_operating_system')); 
$vector_graphic_softwares = count(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_vector_graphics_softwares')); 

$Balance = $modeling_softwares + $database_sofwares + $sig_softwares + $operating_system + $vector_graphic_softwares
```

Comment: if `field_3d_modeling_softwares`, `field_database_management_softwa`, `field_geographic_information_sof`, `field_operating_system`, `field_vector_graphics_softwares` are all entity references, all you are going to get is the node ID, so you will end up just adding the node ID's instead of the actual values. Once you have the node id's you need to load that node (or query the DB) to get the value of field x from node y.  A non coding solution would be to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In fact, what I'm trying to do is to get a count from certains values entered in certains field in user form to make a rule giving a role based on that count. i.e if $balance_computing skill > $balance_fabrication_skills then the user get the role "Computer". Are you that I'm getting the node ID with my code in a computed field (module computed field) ?

Comment: Yes, if your fields [type is entity reference](http://www.gizra.com/assets/images/legacy/3.jpg) using the [entity reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), this field only stores the Node ID. So the value that you're trying to get, is stored in another node (reference node). Therefore, you need to load that node, or query the DB using the ID, in order to retrieve the value of that node. Which is not possible to do with computed field. Either you need a custom module OR use Rules.

Comment: Actually, you probably could load them with Computed Field, since computed field uses the PHP module, but it's best not to enable the PHP module and do things through template files or custom modules as mentioned here [What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-php-filter-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-et)

Comment: Ok, really thanks. I will have a look about those points and if I found the solution will post it here.