# Views filter: show nodes last year

Tags: 7, views

Following this tutorial https://www.drupal.org/node/2481343 i made a filter where the user can select the nodes, createad from a date till now.

Is there an easy way to make a button with 'show nodes from last year'? I was thinking about a button, switchting between 'last year' and 'all' (in fact a reset of the filter).

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful and dynamic but as a quick fix you could for instance add a Global: Text area to your views. (See screenshot also)

```
<a href=http://project.local/articles?created%5Bmin%5D=01%2F01%2F2016&created%5Bmax%5D=12%2F31%2F2016>Show nodes from last year</a>
<a href=http://project.local/articles>Show all nodes</a>
```

To make this more dynamic you could enable the php module (not recommended! https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2512/8606) and use `date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));` to retrieve the previous year dynamically

[image]