# How to show webform results only on pages, where from they has been submitted?

Tags: views, webforms, rating

I have a website with products. By using fivestar and webform fivestar modules i created a simple solution that allows users to add opinion about products.

The 'add opinion' functionality shows on every page with product, but I want also show opinions (webform results) about products only on pages they were submited from.

**More detailed description how I was trying to do that:**

I created a simple webform with 3 fields: comment, fivestar and hidden page URl- which keeps url of the page where comment has been submitted from.
I transformed the webform into block and add the block to page content.

That makes users to add product rating but they didn't see previous ratings.

**To display previous results:**
I created view with block option and added the block to content.

All works ok, except that on every product page every comment is visible. 
I want to make a filter to limit already existing comments to the comments that concern only this product.
My idea was to compare url's in PHP, that's why in form I created a field which keeps the URL of source of content :[current-page:url]

In view I add a PHP field like this:
[image]

Then in filters I made check to eliminate redundant comments:
Filter comment:
[image]

And it's not working,
I even created additional php field to check all variables and the results are ok:
[image]

results: http://plmyhp.platform-preprod.vetoquinol.com/produkty/zdrowie/dermanorm

But it's not working :(
I don't have access to files via ftp or any other all I can do is to use admin panel functions.

I need help, maybe there is other way than using php and comparing website URL's ?

Comment: When trying to view https://www.drupal.org/node/2919223 I get access denied, even after login in.

Comment: Thanks, @NoSssweat I don't know why, I described everything here then.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/249038/1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using Views PHP is considered bad practice. Read: **[What are the downsides of using PHP Filter code in blocks, nodes, views-args, etc?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-php-filter-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args-et/2512)**

Second, I don't like that you're using `$_SERVER{HTTP_HOST]` because if you were to have a development environment, the host name will change; therefore, your functionality will break. Also, if they were to add a subdomain or change the domain name, this will also break your functionality. In summary, any change in the URL will cause critical failure to your functionality.

### The better approach (Use NID's)

Instead of using the URL, a better approach would be to link the webform and the product display node by creating a reference of NID (Node ID). This basically does what you're currently doing, but uses the NID instead of URL.

1. Install [Webform References](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references) module
2. Install [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module, which will allow you to use tokens.
3. Add a Node Reference field to your webform.
4. Create a custom module

/webform_nid_reference/**webform_nid_reference.info**

```
name = Webform NID reference
description = Grabs the current Node ID and puts it the reference field.
package = Webform
version = 7.x-1.0
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = webform
dependencies[] = webform_references
```

/webform_nid_reference/**webform_nid_reference.module**

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */

function webform_nid_reference_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

   if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_475') {

       $form['#validate'][] = 'webform_nid_reference_validate';

   }

}

function webform_nid_reference_validate($form, &$form_state) {

   if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    // Get the nid
    $current_nid = $node->nid;
    // Set webform field value 
    $form_state['values']['submitted']['node_ref_autocomplete'] = $current_nid;

   }   

}
```

6. Enable custom module
7. In [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) remove all of your views php stuff. Under advanced (far right) add a Contextual Filter of your webforms reference field (the field you created in step 3)

   - **When filter value is not in the URL**, Select `provide default value` and select `Content ID from ULR`

Your view will go blank, because the View Edit Page URL does not have a contextual filter. When you go visit a node, the view should show up then.

Comment: The problem while adding the component to the webform is 'Field type'. When I set it to 'Select list' user will see list of the all product and will have to choose one manually (I would prefer this component to be hidden anyway) If I will set it to Autocomplete it stay empty and webpage seems to load incessantly. I was trying to set different default values with autocomplete option and the field stays empty. Check it yourself: http://plmyhp.platform-preprod.vetoquinol.com/produkty/opieka-weterynaryjna/zentonil-advanced

Comment: @Setita updated answer, make the node_ref_autocomplete field have no default value, custom module will take care of it.

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't create new modules, I don't have access to ftp. All I can do is to turn on/of existing ones.